Change the style of the "Attribute Text" shown by Viewer node
Sometimes I find it hard to read the text shown in the 3D Viewport by the Viewer geometry node (based on enabling the Attribute Text setting in the Viewport Overlay menu).

How can I change the color of this text, the color of the outline, the size of the text?

This isn't an answer, but I notice the contrast is a bit better so it's more readable sometimes if I uncheck Viewport Overlays -> Viewer Node -> Color Opacity (or set it to a low value), and maybe Viewport Shading > Lighting > MatCap > check_normal+y.exr (the colorful one).  https://i.sstatic.net/2UrD8QM6.png This is almost always necessary iwhen viewing an Index attribute, for which almost all values are >=1 (white), but sometimes it's not necessary for other attributes which have values between 0 and 1, for which the Viewer's coloring sometimes has good contrast with the text by luck.

Text attributes are controlled by the following theme settings:

Fill Color: view_3d.space.text_hi; in Preferences as:
Themes ▸ 3D Viewport ▸ Theme Space ▸ Text Highlight
Outline Color: view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient; in Preferences as:
Themes ▸ 3D Viewport ▸ Theme Space ▸ Gradient Colors ▸ Gradient High/Off
Font Size: (cannot find API for this); in Preferences as:
Themes ▸ Text Style ▸ Widget Label ▸ Points

Note that you probably only want to adjust the fill color of the text; the outline color is shared with the 3D Viewport's background, and the font size is shared with various other UI elements throughout the interface:

To change the fill color with script, you can do:
bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.text_hi[:] = (1, 0, 1) # magenta

This answer current as of Blender 4.2.1

Are you sure this is current?  In 4.2.3 (the same as 4.2.1, I would hope), I am trying changing the value of "Themes ▸ Text Style ▸ Widget Label ▸ Points" as you suggest; it is changing the size of various text (including the text in the very preferences panel in which I'm interacting-- fun!)  but unfortunately it is not changing the Viewer Attribute Text size which is what I want to make bigger.
